# What Variable type can hold a LinQ results?

Tags: vb.net, linq

I have the below code

```
Dim LinQuery = From product In AppData.ProductInfo
                       Where product.Product_Name Like Keyword Or
                           product.SubCatogory_Name Like Keyword Or
                           product.SWC Like Keyword
                       Select Brand = product.Brand_Name,
                           Name = product.Product_Name,
                           Code = product.Product_code,
                           Category = product.SubCatogory_Name,
                           InitialStock = product.Init_Stock,
                           CurrentStock = product.Current_Stock
```

Can somebody tell me which variable type can hold LinQ results, in my case 'LinQuery '.

My intention is to create a public function that returns a LinkQ result. For that I have to write what type of variable that the function returns.

Comment: In this case you have an [anonymous type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/objects-and-classes/anonymous-types). If you want to return the results, project the data to a class you have created.

Comment: If you don't mind please explain 'project the data to a class'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case you have an [anonymous type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/objects-and-classes/anonymous-types). If you want to return the results, project the data to a class you have created. For example (and my VB.Net is very rusty so this may need tweaking) create a new class:

```
Public Class Foo
    Public Property Brand As String
    Public Property Name As String
    Public Property Code As String
    Public Property Category As String
    Public Property InitialStock As Integer
    Public Property CurrentStock As Integer
End Class
```

And your Linq query would change to this:

```
Dim query As IEnumerable(Of Foo) =
            From product In AppData.ProductInfo
            Where product.Product_Name Like Keyword Or
                  product.SubCatogory_Name Like Keyword Or
                  product.SWC Like Keyword
            Select New Foo With {
                .Brand = product.Brand_Name,
                .Name = product.Product_Name,
                .Code = product.Product_code,
                .Category = product.SubCatogory_Name,
                .InitialStock = product.Init_Stock,
                .CurrentStock = product.Current_Stock }
```

Comment: Thanks.. I will check and update the question status.